# ajax function in drupal 6 not working

Tags: ajax, drupal

I need to filter the territory field upon the value of the region    field im using ajax function like it's mentioned in the below code    but it's not working. THE AJAX CALL on the fonction is not getting into the function 'territory_filter_callback' anyway would know where is the error?

```
            function form_search_menu() {

             $items['form/search'] = array(
             'title' => t('Search'),
             'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
             'page arguments' => array('_search'),
             'access callback' => TRUE,
             'description' => t('search'),
               );
            return $items;
              }

         function _search(&$form_state) {
         drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'form_search')    .'/script.js');
           $form['description'] = array(
           '#type' => 'item',
           '#title' => t('Search page'),
                );



       //FILL THE LIST OF REGIONS
         $conn = oci_connect('webuser', 'website',    '172.16.1.1');

        //regions
      $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECt  code,descr1 FROM    table1.region");
   oci_execute($stid);
    $cidades = array();         while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,    OCI_ASSOC))) {
            $cidades[$row['CODE']]= $row['DESCR1'];
                                }       $cidades ['']='Select';

        //city
        $stid1 = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT code,descr1 from    table1.city ORDER BY      DESCR1");   oci_execute($stid1);    $types =    array();        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid1, OCI_ASSOC))) {
            $types [$row['CODE']]= $row['DESCR1'];
                                }           $types['']='Select';
  //territory
   $stid2 = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT code,descr1 FROM    table1.territory");      oci_execute($stid2);
    $territory = array();
      while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_ASSOC))) {
             $territory [$row['CODE']]= $row['DESCR1'];
                                }
         $territory ['']='Select';


   oci_free_statement($stid);
   oci_close($conn);


$form['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  //'#title' => t('Name'),
  // Make the fieldset collapsible.
  '#collapsible' => false, // Added
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,  // Added
  ); 

  $form['name']['Region'] = array(
 '#type' => 'select',
 '#title' => t('Region'),
 '#options' => $cidades,  
 '#required' => FALSE,    '#default_value' =>    isset($form_state['values']['name']['Region']) ? $form_state     ['values']['name']['Region'] : '',
       '#ajax' => array(
          'event' => 'change',
         'callback' => 'territory_filter_callback', 
          'wrapper' => 'dropdown_second_replace'
     ),
  // Added
     );

 $form['name']['Territory'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
   '#title' => t('Territory'),      '#prefix' => '<div    id="dropdown_second_replace">',   '#suffix' => '</div>',  
    '#options' => $territory,
     '#required' => FALSE,  '#default_value' =>    isset($form_state['values']['name']['Territory']) ?             $form_state['values']['name']['Territory'] : '',

       // Added    );

    $form['name']['City'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('City'),
       '#options' => $types,
     '#required' => FALSE,
   // Added
 );

 $form['link'] = array(
 '#type' => 'markup',
 '#value' => '<a href="#" onclick="navigate()" ><input    type="button"  value="Search"         style="background-color:#2A64A9;color:#FFFFFF;width:80px;    height:25px;         border:1;CURSOR:POINTER;float:right;border-color:#FFFFFF;" ></a>', //



  return $form;
 }

   function territory_filter_callback(&$form,&$form_state)
{
$territory_options=array();
   if(isset($form['name']['Region']['#default_value']['0'])
{   $Region=$form['name']['Region']['#default_value']['0'];
}
else
  {     $Region=0;
   }


   $territory_options=selected_territory($Region);
   $form['name']['Region']['#ajax']=
   array('event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'territory_wrapper',
   'callback' => 'filter_territory_callback',
   'method' =>replace,
   );
   $form ['name']['territory']['prefix']='<div    id="territory_wrapper">';
      $form ['name']['territory']['prefix']='</div>';
       $form ['territory']['#options']=$territory_options;

  }

  function filter_territory_callback($form,$form_state)
 {
    $Region=$form['name']['Region']['#value'];
$form['name']['territory']['#options']=selected_territory($Region);
return $form['territory'];
  }
```

Comment: I can't really see any question mark. I'd be happy to remove my downvote if you rewrite your "question" and add a little more details about what you've done and specifically can't get to work. Furthermore, It would be great if you could format your code so that it is a little easier to read. Consider using the same indentation through your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drupal 6 not support '#ajax'...'#ajax' is working with drupal 7...in drupal 6 you can use '#ahah'

http://drupal.org/node/331941

good luck